# How to get "real" ChildNodes of XmlNode, ignoring whitespace nodes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Apparently XmlNode.ChildNodes-list (in C# .Net) contains not only real child nodes, but also special whitespace nodes. So even in the simplest case when having one tag inside another you can get parentNode.ChildNodes.Count == 3. How to get around this?

Already tried:

```
xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = false;
```

Also:

```
foreach(XmlNode node in xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//*))
  if (node is XmlWhitespace)
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text nodes are first class children. I guess you want Element nodes only. Can't you do

```
node.SelectNodes("*")
```

Or are you saying that `<root><child></root>` results in root having three child nodes?

Comment: Yes, SelectNodes("*") works, but I'm still baffled that ChildNodes-array is completely unusable in .net. Why it exits...

Comment: "Useless" depends on your needs. Why shouldn't there be a way to get hold of all child nodes of an element, including Text, Comment and PI nodes?

Comment: I guess there should be two arrays, ChildNodes and AllChildNodes. It doesn't make sense that default list doesn't correspond to the list of tags (in xml).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the following? You won't be able to remove the node from the parent, because then you're modifying the collection while you're enumerating which isn't allowed.

```
foreach(XmlNode node in xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//*"))
{
  if (node is XmlWhitespace)
    continue;
  else
  {
     // A real node
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simple like this.

```
xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//*).OfType<XmlElement>();
```

This will filter for only nodes of type XmlElement (meaning "real" nodes). it will exclude CData, whitespace, text, etc.

Make sure to add Linq namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```