# Iterate each node in XmlDocument by what it contains

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having a difficult time determining while iterating each node in an XML document (recursively) determining if the current node has a value, or, if it has embedded XML.

It seems that XmlNode.NodeType is set to Element in both cases, and in cases where the XML has a value (and not more XML) the ChildNodes.Count is not null (actually, it's 1).

A simple XML file I'm using for testing is:

```
<note>
  <to>You</to>
  <from>Me</from>
  <subject>Hello!</subject>
  <body>Check out this cool data!</body>
  <data>
    <name>Something cool</name>
    <location>Mars</location>
    <distance>54 million kilometers</distance>
  </data>
</note>
```

Each of the XmlNodes above is 'Element' and with ChildNodes >= 1.

What can I use to reliably test if an XmlNode should be treated as a container (like note and data) or as holding a value (like to, from, subject, body, name, location, distance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can use `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` instead of `XmlDocument` here but if you can, you can go about this the following way:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("<note> .... </note>");
```

then

```
xml.Elements().Count()
```

returns `5` the correct number of subnodes, whereas

```
xml.Elements().First().Elements().Count()
```

returns `0` because the `to` node has zero children...

Comment: This could work, is there a foreach I can use on the children for the container?

Comment: @joelc you can write a regular foreach - `foreach (var element in xml.Elements()) { /* your code */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Usually you know what nodes contain values by knowing structure of XML.

If you need to infer that information from XML of any structure - text represented by TEXT and CDATA nodes so you can check if element has only children of those types to get "text only" nodes. See [How to get text inside an XmlNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266647/how-to-get-text-inside-an-xmlnode-c).

Some gotcha to be aware of/make decisions about:

- mixed content nodes (`<r>foo <v/> bar</r>`) - decide what you want to do with them. I.e. nodes with HTML content generally contain "mixed content".
- text nodes representing insignificant white-space between elements (`<r>  <n/>   </r>`). You should ignore those unless you must preserve document formatting
- multiple nodes representing single piece of text. Depending on a way XML is loaded or constructed single pieces of text may be represented by collection of child text nodes instead of a single node.

Comment: In this case I don't know anything about the structure. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you could check for the 1st child node being of type `Element`.

```
bool isContainer(XmlNode node) {
  return node.ChildNodes.Count > 0 && node.ChildNodes[0].NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element;
}
```

Note that this will not handle mixed content data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers from this post to see if it gets you going in the right direction:

[How to get "real" ChildNodes of XmlNode, ignoring whitespace nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022441/how-to-get-real-childnodes-of-xmlnode-ignoring-whitespace-nodes)